# How to delete an unsaved managed object safely?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

My app offers some sort of editor functionality for "text articles". My editor has two modes. When the editor loads, I create a managed object if it hasn't been passed in through the initializer. When the user cancels a new edit, I delete the object from the context. However, sometimes,I get an error about the object not being inserted into the context, and sometimes I don't. So, is the following code a good approach to check if a managed object instance was inserted into a context?

```
if ([[self.workingManagedObjectInstance managedObjectContext] isEqual:self.managedObjectContext]){

}
```

My theory is that if `[self.workingManagedObjectInstance managedObjectContext]` is `nil`, then it hasn't been inserted and will not be "`isEqual`".  Is that a valid way to check that we're not deleting an object that wasn't inserted yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I realized that I should be saving my context after creating the initial instance of the managed object. Since I still had a reference to it, I was able to delete it later.

Answer (score 1):

If possible should always use the same managed object context, not various instances of it. If you have more than one view controller, you should pass the same context as a reference. Comparing the context does not tell you anything about the existence of an entity instance.

After you initialize the object in the usual way

```
myEntity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Entity" 
   inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

you can check if it exists and delete it with a simple

```
if (myEntity) { 
   [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:myEntity];
}
```